# Material UI React: Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the [material-ui React components](http://www.material-ui.com) in my app. I'm using webpack and installed material-ui with npm. I have already replaced text inputs in my forms with the material-ui text-field and it works great.

But.

Then I tried adding a button. Simple enough right? Suddenly, I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: ReactClass: You're attempting to use a component class as a mixin. Instead, just use a regular object
```

I have tested and this error gets thrown even if I just load in an otherwise empty Javascript file with this line:

```
require('material-ui/lib/raised-button');
```

If I remove that line, everything works fine. It's weird because the text-field works, so I know my setup is correct. I suspect there is a Mixin being used inside the button code?

Has anyone experienced this? Information on this is sparse, any help is appreciated.

Comment: open an issue in their repo on github

Comment: I suppose you're doing `var RaisedButton = require('material-ui/lib/raised-button');` ?

Comment: Yes, why? Does it have to be a const?